# How to use 'hr' tag after every row in between ng-repeat while displaying multiple checkboxes using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to add

---

line after every row . But I am unable to do as I am using ng-repeat for displaying checkbox list. Can anybody help me in my code.
below is my code-

```
 <div>Check All
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>
        </div>
       <div ng-repeat="item in Items">

  <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />{{item.Name}}
            </label>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I want to add 'hr' line after check all, then after Item 3 and at last item Item6.  can anybody tell me wher should I put this hr tag so that I will get a line after every row? Here is [my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jSTCuj9dEZ5epTfAVUxM?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this by using `ng-repeat-start`/`ng-repeat-end` syntax in combination with ng-if and repeat $index for showing only after every third item.

```
<hr>
<div class="row" ng-repeat-start="item in Items">
  ..
</div>
<hr ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index % 3 === 2">
```

See updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J7C7gCe6osmwggznSVhX?p=preview)

---

### Edit

What you conceptually want your HTML to look like is this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
<hr />
...
```

One option is to use an outer and inner ng-repeat. First transform the list of items from `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]` to `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h]]`. Then we can repeat over each "group" first for the rows, then repeat over individual items for columns.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat-start="group in Items | groupArray:3">
  <div class="col-4" ng-repeat="item in group"></div>
<hr ng-repeat-end />
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9xLF6p18eB6D31qx2k9x?p=preview) showing how it can be done.

*Note: This option carries a significantly larger performance hit, due to having multiple ng-repeats.*

---

If you don't use bootstraps `row`/`col-*` classes, it's possible to create a custom component for displaying content in columns. This takes more work, but could be much more performant. I won't provide an code example here, but it could work kinda like this:

```
<my-column-component items="myItems" columns="3">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$item.selected"> {{ $item.name }}
  </label>
</my-column-component>
```

Comment: The three items should come in three columns in a row , in your code three items are coming in separate lines, i want those to be in one row .@Csvn

Comment: @Aanchal In columns the way you explained is a bit more involved, but I added some more info in my edit above

Answer (score 1):

like this one?

```
<div>
     Check All
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>
     <hr />
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in Items">
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />{{item.Name}}
         </label>
         <hr />
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it is not showing the whole line in between rows. see here-https://plnkr.co/edit/zPTMz3Z1qfqpXLoTDwun?p=preview

Comment: Oh, sry about that. it's my shitty monitor :/ Seems @Csvn's code does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in Items"><div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />{{item.Name}}
        </label>
        </div>
        <br>
         <hr>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat over multiple DOMnodes by using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

```
<div>Check All
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat-start="item in Items">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
        {{item.Name}}
    </label>
</div>
<hr ng-repeat-end>
```